# How to use like with between in where clause

Tags: sql-server-2008

Dear all I am trying to use like statement with where clause,
as shown,

```
select  
  Col1 
from 
  Table
where 
  Col2 between ( case when Col2 ='' or col2 is null then '%' else 'Userinputmin' end) 
and
  ( case when Col2 ='' or col2 is null then '%' else 'Userinputmax' end)
```

If user inputs a character value in col2, then it will be filtered from its maximum and minimum value, and if user doesnt inputs any value, then I want to use all the values.
Thank you for any help.
Regards.

Comment: Please chek now, I missed to write else there, I have to write user input if user inputs a value, else I will use all the values

Answer (score 0):

Implying @min and @max is a parameter

```
IF @min IS NOT NULL AND @max IS NOT NULL
    SELECT * FROM Tbl WHERE col BETWEEN @min AND @max

ELSE
    SELECT * FROM Tbl
```

Since you are doing this in your aspx page, perhaps something like this will work if you put this in the "behind code" page.

```
if (min != null && max != null)
{
    sqlcmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Tbl WHERE col BETWEEN " + min + " AND " + max
}
else  
{
    sqlcmd.Commandtext = "SELECT * FROM Tbl"
}
```

Comment: I cannot use any programing here, I have to control this in my query, code cannot be changed.

Comment: I'm confused what you're trying to say, do you mean you can't use parameter? If so, then how do you catch user input without parameters?

Comment: I am using this query in aspx page, and getting input using getfield function.

Comment: I just edited my solution, please check if something like this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
select  
  Col1 
from 
  Table
where 
  (Col2 between 'Userinputmin' AND 'Userinputmax') OR (Col2 Like 'Userinputmin%') OR (Col2 Like 'Userinputmax%')
```